# Cumulocity tracker-agent stuck at "Start bootstraping"

Tags: cumulocity

I have trouble with one of my devices (Tracker dongle) communicating with Cumulocity. I used the Device Registration interface to register its IMEI. Then I accepted it in the same interface when it first connected. But now the tracker-agent I deployed is continually logging:

> c.t.d.DeviceBootstrapProcessor           : Start bootstrapping:
>   (DEVICE_IMEI)

And I got nothing arriving on Cumulocity. So I'm guessing it's stuck trying to retreive the device credentials? (Cf. DeviceBootstrapProcessor.tryAccessDeviceCredentials). I have another device of the same type which worcks just fine in the same configuration and I can't tell what's the difference between the two. Is there a step I'm missing to correctly register a device?

Answer (score 0):

The tracker-agent has an additional registration for itself. It is once per tenant and automatically triggers after registering the first tracker device.

What you need to do is register the agent (via device registration) with the following ID:

tracker-agent-{tenant}

(replace {tenant} with the tenant you want do register the agent). This needs do be done once per tenant to allow the tracker agent to create devices and data.

Comment: Okay so what happened was I registered my device, then I made it communicate through tracker-agent A which was deployed on my local machine and it worked fine. Then I tried to make it communicate through tracker-agent B deployed on a server and it fell into that bootstraping loop. When I deleted the device and did the accept after making it communicate through B, then it could work with B, but now when I try to make it communicate with A, I get an explicit 403 error.

Comment: But tracker agents A and B can create devices, but once I register a device with one, it gets denied access when connecting through the other.

Comment: And I dont understand why on B, I fall in the bootstrap loop but on A, I got a com.cumulocity.sdk.client.SDKException: Http status code: 403.